# Java is not recognizing an object created as an array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am creating a simple mechanical computer emulator, with virtual counters and punch cards, but I keep getting errors in java.
It creates counters as an array of objects like this:

```
private static void createcounters(int counternums, int digits,
        int[] countervals){
    for (int i=0; i<counternums; i++){
        try {
            if (digits < 1){
                System.out.println("Invalid number of digits, reverting to 1 digit");
                digits = 1;
            }
            Counter[] counter = null;
            counter[i] = new Counter(digits, countervals[i]);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

}
```

The object is referenced at a different point in a program to read values and put those in a integer array:

```
public int[] getcounters(){
    int[] countervals = null;
    for (int i=0; i<counternums; i++){
        countervals[i] = counter[i].ReturnVal;           
    }
    return countervals;
}
```

Java gives this error on compiliation:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable counter
  location: class mechanicalcomputeremulator.Computer
    at mechanicalcomputeremulator.Computer.getcounters(Computer.java:49)
    at mechanicalcomputeremulator.MechanicalComputerEmulator.main(MechanicalComputerEmulator.java:20)
Java Result: 1
```

If I reference the counter in the method that the objects are created, the error doesn't appear.

Comment: Where did `counter` in `getcounters` come from?

Comment: your array is local scope to the method

Comment: `counter` is initialized and given a value in a completely different scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got at least four problems:

- You're declaring the `counter` variable as a *local* variable inside your method. I suspect you meant to declare a *field* somewhere - or return a reference from the method, and assign it to an instance variable there.
- You're initializing the variable to `null` and then immediately trying to dereference it. How do you expect that to work?
- You're declaring a different variable for each iteration of the loop. I strongly suspect you mean to declare *one* variable and populate the same array in all iterations.
- You're catching `Exception` and just ignoring it. **Never do that.** (Ideally don't do either part of it.)

So sample better code:

```
private static void createCounters(int counterNums,
                                   int digits,
                                   int[] counterVals) {
    // Moved out of the loop, as it's pointless there.
    if (digits < 1) {
        // TODO: Throw an exception instead?
        System.out.println("Invalid number of digits, reverting to 1 digit");
        digits = 1;
    }
    counter = new Counter[counterNums];
    for (int i=0; i < counterNums; i++) {
        counter[i] = new Counter(digits, counterVals[i]);
    }    
}
```

Or:

```
private static Counter[] createCounters(int counterNums,
                                        int digits,
                                        int[] countervals) {
    if (digits < 1) {
        // TODO: Throw an exception instead?
        System.out.println("Invalid number of digits, reverting to 1 digit");
        digits = 1;
    }
    Counter[] counter = new int[counterNums];
    for (int i=0; i < counterNums; i++) {

        counter[i] = new Counter(digits, counterBals[i]);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Note that if `counterNums` is the same as the length of `counterVals`, you can remove that parameter and just use `counterVals.length`.

Comment: `You're initializing the variable to null and then immediately trying to dereference it. How do you expect that to work?` I think the better question is: what is the point?

Comment: I corrected the createcounters method, added 'private int countervals[];' at the beginning of the class, and removed the null assignment, but now I get a NullPointerException at 'countervals[i] = counter[i].ReturnVal();' in the getcounters method. Shouldn't the for loop initialize the variable?

Comment: Additionally, if I add 'int countervals[] = int[counternums];' to the method, java says that it has an unexpected type, requiring a value, but finding a class.

Comment: @DanielM.: You're now talking about code which isn't present in this question. One question per post, please. (For your last question, you're missing a `new`...)

Comment: Thanks- I played around with the debugger a bit, and found that I defined a method-scope counter **and** a class-scope counter, so the class-scope one remained null, while the method one was written to, then promptly garbage collected. (facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

`Counter[] counter` in `createCounters` is a *method-scoped* variable. It will not be available in a different method. If you want to make it available to all methods in your class then it needs to be a field.

However, you need to be aware you are using static on the `createcounters` method, so you can't access an instance field unless you remove the static keyword on the method.

You also can't do `Counter[] counter = null;` and then assign values to it, you need to do `Counter[] counter = new Counter[size];`. I suspect you also want an expandable array, so should use an `ArrayList` instead.

```
public class MyClass {
  private Counter[] counter = new Counter[10]; // arbitrary fixed size array
  private /*static*/ void createcounters(int counternums, int digits,
    int[] countervals){
   ...
    counter[i] = new Counter(digits, countervals[i]);
  }
  public int[] getcounters(){
    int[] countervals = null;
    for (int i=0; i<counternums; i++){
        countervals[i] = counter[i].ReturnVal;           
    }
    return countervals;
  }
}
```